# Can I successfully obtain a PS+ account from Europe with a US PSN account?

Tags: psn, ps4, playstation-plus

I am from Europe and have a US PSN account. If I buy Playstation Plus through the PS Store, will I be able to play online multiplayer games through that account as I'm not from US?

Comment: My question would be, why would you have an US account to start with? Is it really necessary? As far as I know there are quite a few downsides, like being unable to buy anything digitally (so you might not be able to buy Plus to start with) as well as applying prepaid cards (you'd need US ones, too).

Comment: 40% lower prices than my country's, and yeah you can buy stuff through the store. I'm just not sure if PS+ will work.
As for the prepaid cards, I'm going to get games off eBay for the US region, and if I really want to purchase something digitally, I'll use a VISA.
I wouldn't bother this much but a $45 difference per game isn't small money.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's really allowed (carefully reread the terms of use). If you don't have to use VPN or similar services, it's most likely okay to use, but if you'd have to fake your location in some way (fake address or using VPN/proxies to fake an US IP), then definitely don't do it, it will most likely be a violation of the terms, which might get your account suspended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work. You can buy PSN cards online, such as on Amazon, but make sure you purchase a US PSN card. Once you've purchased it, a code will automatically be sent to your email. If you have other accounts and want to buy PS+, all other accounts will also have PS+. The same goes for DLCs and downloaded games. However, this can happen *only* if the US account is the primary account.

In addition, make sure all accounts are set up *before* buying PS+. I made this stupid mistake of making my US account, purchasing PS+ and *then* creating a new user, so that new user didn't get PS+ because I created it after buying PS+ on the primary account.

Answer (score -1):

I created [this guide for creating an US PSN account](http://www.xtremeps3.com/2008/06/13/how-do-i-purchase-items-from-the-playstation-store-from-another-country/) a while ago. Although the screenshots are now old, the process is still valid. Essentially, you need a Virtual Credit Card to use on the US Store, and just sign-up using a fake US address.